# how to load dynamic images into a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dynamic, slideshow

I want to create a page where the user can choose the images that will be shown in a slideshow. I'm attempting to use imgchecked.js and would like to use lightgallery.js.

How can I pass an array of images into the dynamicEL? 
Is there a way to load the images using the class imgchecked?

Any help is greatly appreciated. And apologies in advance for being new at coding.

Here is a jsfiddle that only seems to be slightly working in chrome:
imgcheckbox with lightgallery - https://jsfiddle.net/ssab/cydgs40n/13/
Thanks

```
<div class="slides">
   <ul>
       <li><img src="001.jpg" /></li>
       <li><img src="002.jpg" /></li>
       <li><img src="003.jpg" /></li>
       <li><img src="004.jpg" /></li>
   </ul>
   <button id="dynamic">Launch Gallery</button>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(".slides img").imgCheckbox();

$('#dynamic').on('click', function() {
   $(this).lightGallery({
       dynamic: true,
       dynamicEl: [{ }]
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I want to do but the images src are written out in the code. how do I get the img src code in there without writing the specific images?  I want the user to be able to click 1 or 2 or 10 images and then launch the gallery. Is it possible to populate the gallery somehow by naming a class for example "imgchecked" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make code formatting well but you can find your solution here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbGzPM?editors=1111

The idea is you have to prepare object array each time dynamic button clicked and pass that array to `dynamicEL`.

Note: please clean and improve sample code before use or let me know.

Comment: Yes! Great! thanks so much, that certainly seems to work!

Comment: Any chance you know of a way to have the images shown in the order that they are clicked on?  Asking a lot here I know!

Comment: Its ok no problem. If you want to order by the image selected then after every image click you have to populate the array which we are now creating after button click. As you are using imagecheck library which handles the image click event; need to hack that and if they provide any api then you can do rest as I said

Comment: @mero it's nice that you are trying different solutions. Lets open a new question so that in future viewers will get 2 different solutions.